# Websocket sharp log file output

Tags: c#, websocket-sharp

I'm using Websocket sharp (https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) for a console program, how do I output all debug/trace information that are displayed on the console to a text file?

For example:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket(WebAddr))
            {

                ws.Log.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
                ws.OnOpen += (ss, ee) =>
                {
                  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\log.txt", ws.Log.ToString());

                };
```

But the output for this is "WebSocketSharp.Logger".

I would expecting something like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLCxX.png)

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\log.txt", wWebSocket.Log.ToString()); but it only ouput "WebSocketSharp.Logger"

Answer (score 3):

Set the property `File`:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket(WebAddr))
{
    ws.Log.Level = LogLevel.Debug;

    ws.Log.File = @"C:\log.txt";
}
```

Comment: Since this solved your issue, you should click the green checkmark to mark as the answer. It gives points to the answerer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide alot more information (which data?, how often? etc.) but you can use the System.IO.File methods for easy writing to a file;

```
// To create a new file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"FileNameToWriteTo.txt", aString);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"FileNameToWriteTo.txt", listOfStrings);

// To add to the end of an existing file
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"FileNameToWriteTo.txt", aString);
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"FileNameToWriteTo.txt", listOfStrings);
```

Comment: I've edited my original questions, hope make more sense now.